# Google Maps API gestures not working (zoom-rotate...)

Tags: android, google-maps, pinchzoom

**Edit: I found my problem see my answer below**

**Original post:**
I am creating an activity that contains a map, but I cannot add zooming and other gestures capability. I can double tap to zoom in, and I can add the +/- sign to zoom via

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
```

This is my code:

Activity's xml (tracking_order.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    class="com.example.OrderMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/clientsFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

OrderMapFragment.java

```
public class OrderMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    public static OrderMapFragment newInstance() {
        OrderMapFragment fragment = new OrderMapFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        ((OrderMapFragment.OnOrderMarkerClickListener) context).setMapObject(this);
        getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true); //this one is working
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true); //not working

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);  //not working
        // ... (removed code used to fetch markers data)
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return listener.filterListByMarker(marker);
    }

    public interface OnOrderMarkerClickListener {
        /**
         * Action to be taken when a marker has been clicked
         *
         * @param marker
         * @return true if the listener has consumed the event (i.e., the default behavior should not occur);
         * false otherwise (i.e., the default behavior should occur).
         * The default behavior is for the camera to move to the marker and an info window to appear.
         */
        boolean filterListByMarker(Marker marker); //the class that implements this doesn't do anything for now it just returns false
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem:
The activity containing the `mapFragment` was extending a custom class. That class had overriden the following method:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    if (ev.getPointerCount() > 1)  //here was the problem
        return true;
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

so I created a method and changed it to this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    if (ev.getPointerCount() > 1 && !enableMultiTouch())
        return true;
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

protected boolean enableMultiTouch(){
    return false;  //and override it to true in my activity
}
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

Comment this line

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true); //not working
```

Now you try, it will work. If you need any particular or few Gestures means, enable by separate otherwise if you need all just call this line

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
```

Comment: At first I've tried without any of the 3 lines. Then I tried with `setZoomControlsEnabled` but it wasn't what I needed, then I tried with each of the others seperately and neither worked. Then I put all of them and asked the question here

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to set `map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);` and to override lifecycle methods as described in [`MapView` documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView):

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        mapView.onCreate(bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState()
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState();
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory()
    {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }
```